# How can I extract only numbers from a string?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to extract only numbers from a string, and to put them in an array.

For example, string is `"fds34 21k34 k25j 6 10j340ii0i5"`.

I want to make one array, which elements are like following:

```
arr[0]=34, arr[1]=21, arr[2]=34, arr[3]=25, arr[4]=6, arr[5]=10, arr[6]=340, arr[7]=0, arr[8]=5;
```

my trial code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    int i, j;
    int pr[100];
    i=0;
    while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' ){
        if( ch>='0' && ch<='9' ){
            pr[i] = ch-'0';
            i++;
    }
    for(j=0; j<i; j++)
        printf("pr[%d]: %d\n", j, pr[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

My code cannot recognize the contiguous number. just '`pr`' array has `{3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5}`. Is there any method to implement my objective?

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Actually, I don't have my code. I was just wondering how to find only numbers in string. Then, I tried to make some code, which is to exact numbers in a string. But I failed to make it. But I will edit the part of code, wait please

Comment: Keep a temporary `char*`, store the numbers as `char`s, convert to `int`, then add to your `int[]` when you run into whitespace

Comment: You should divide your problem into two areas: (1.) Find the start and end position (or length) of a series of digits within your string (2.) Convert a given range of character digits into a single number

Comment: A string is run time input.

Comment: How do you want to handle `'-'` and `'+'`?   Should these characters be allowed as part of _numbers_ or are you only interested in the ten digits?

Comment: I didn't think about sign.... Hmm. I want to handle it too. I'm so greedy. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scanf. Life becomes simpler when you use standard functions instead of making up your own algorithms.

This code uses scan read a line of user input and then parses it. Detected digits are put into an array and the search index is shifted forward by the number of digits.

```
char line[100];
int p[100];
int readNums = 0;
int readDigits = 0;
int len;
int index = 0;

//get line
scanf("%99[^\n]%n",line,&len);

while( index < len ){
    if(line[index] <= '9' && line[index] >= '0'){
        if(sscanf(line + index, "%d%n", p + readNums, &readDigits) != 1)
            fprintf(stderr, "failed match!!!! D:\n");
        index += readDigits;
        readNums++;
    }
    index++;
}

//print results
printf("read %d ints\n", readNums);

for(int i = 0; i < readNums; i++)
    printf("p[%d] = %d\n", i, p[i]);
```

Comment: Note that `scanf("%99[^\n]%n",line,&len);` reads nothing into `line` and leaves `line` and `len` uninitialized should input be `"\n"`.

Comment: @chux what do you mean? `scanf("%99[^\n]%n",line,&len);` reads up to 99 characters that aren't the new line character. What do you think it does? Could you try running the code?

Comment: "`scanf("%99[^\n]%n",line,&len);` reads up to 99 characters that aren't the new line character." is not correct is the _first_ character is `'\n'`.  What it does in that case is as [commented beforehand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972278/how-can-i-extract-only-numbers-from-a-string/33973405?noredirect=1#comment55703060_33973405).  Yes I can run the code and get undefined behavior when the first `char` is a '\n'.  What do you expect to happen if the first character entered is `'\n'`?  Did you try?

Comment: What would work better? I'm not familiar with using fgets() with stdin, and went for an easy solution since I figured this was a homework question

Answer (score 2):

That is algorithm:

- Use a string to store current number. At first, init it as empty string
- when ch is a digit('0'..'9'), put it in this string
- when ch is not a digit, if string is not empty, convert current string to number by **atoi** function, and store that number in array. After that, init current string to empty again.

Ex: i have string "ab34 56d1"

- use string str to store current number, at first str =""(empty)
- ch = 'a', do nothing (because current string is empty)
- ch = 'b', do nothing
- ch = '3', put it to string, so str = "3"
- ch = '4', put it to str, now str = "34"
- ch = ' ', convert "34" to 34, save it in array, init str="" again
- .....

Comment: Why can't I think this algorithm? When I read some ways to make code, I consider that it is not hard. But when I tried to make one, it is so difficult... Very Thank you. I will try to make the code using this algorithm.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think it easy to understand and develop. Try to code it and ask me if you meet problem.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer

Answer (score 2):

Create a *state machine*.

Keep track of the previous character - was it a digit?

When a digit is detected ...
...  If continuing a digit sequence, *10 and add
...  Else start new sequence

Do not overfill `pr[]`

Use `int ch` to properly detect `EOF`

```
//char ch;
int ch;
bool previous_digit = false;
int pr[100];
int i = 0 - 1;
while (i < 100 && (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
  if (ch>='0' && ch<='9') {
    if (previous_digit) {
      pr[i] = pr[i] * 10 + ch - '0';
    } else {
      i++;
      pr[i] = ch - '0';
    }
    previous_digit = true;
  } else {
    previous_digit = false;
  }
}
i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code. I try 3-4 times it works fine.
chPrevious will hold the previous state of ch. There is no need to store the digits into the string of digit. We can simply use an integer for this purpose.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NONDIGIT 'a'

int main() {
    char ch, chPrevious; //chPrevious hold the previous state of ch.
    chPrevious = NONDIGIT;
    int temp = 0;
    int pr[100];
    int i = 0;
    while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' ){
    if( (ch>='0' && ch<='9') && (chPrevious>='0' && chPrevious<= '9')){
        temp = temp * 10 + (ch - '0');
    } else if (ch>= '0' && ch<= '9' && temp != 0) {
        pr[i++] = temp;
        temp = 0;
        temp = ch - '0';
    } else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
        temp = ch-'0';
    }
    chPrevious = ch;
    }
    pr[i++] = temp;
     for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        printf("pr[%d]: %d\n", j, pr[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

There may be other way too do to this and efficient also. Please ignore the bad styling. You should also improve this code as well.

Comment: There are merits to using `isdigit()` from `<ctypes.h>`.

Comment: Input "0 1 2\n" --> `pr[0]: 1` `pr[1]: 2`.  Missing first number

Comment: @chux Yup you are right. I found your one more efficient so upvoted. Still i'm on learning stage.

Comment: FWIW, did not see yours before posting.  The corner case here is using `temp == 0` to indicate a new `int` when `0` is a valid `int`.  Perhaps using `-1` as the _not used_ value.